# Custom User and Claims Stores but no claims get set on Controller.User

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

```
      // ASP.NET Identity
            serviceRegistry.For<IPasswordHasher<User>>().Add<CustomPasswordHasher>();

            serviceRegistry.For<CustomDbContext>()
                .Use(s => new DesignTimeDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext(Array.Empty<string>()))
                .Scoped();

            serviceRegistry.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();
            serviceRegistry.AddTransient<IUserClaimStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();

            serviceRegistry.AddIdentityCore<User>();

            serviceRegistry.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            }).AddIdentityCookies();
```

I then sign in using the following in my controller action...

```
 var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Username, model.Password, false, false );
```

.. and I see UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.GenerateClaimsAsync calling my custom claims store and receiving the expected list of claims.

I have set a break point just beyond the PasswordSignInAsync call but when I look at the User property on the controller there are no claims on there.

Would seem either my config is up the creek, I am missing some code or the order of what I am doing is incorrect or all of the previous! :-(

(All code is work in progress and by no means production ready!)

EDIT:

```
// I am using Lamar so this is the same as Startup.ConfigureContainer
        public static void Configure(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var clients = ClientHelper.GetClients(configuration);

            var tenants = new TenantFactory().CreateTenants(clients);

            serviceRegistry.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            serviceRegistry.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureMvcOptions>();
            serviceRegistry.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureMvcViewOptions>();
            serviceRegistry.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureRazorViewOptions>();
            serviceRegistry.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSessionOptions>();
            serviceRegistry.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureAntiforgeryOptions>();

            serviceRegistry.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            serviceRegistry.AddSession();

            serviceRegistry.AddMvc()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    {
                        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                    });

            serviceRegistry.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.FormFieldName = "__RequestVerificationToken");

            serviceRegistry.AddRouteAnalyzer();


            // ASP.NET Identity
            serviceRegistry.For<CustomDbContext>()
                .Use(s => new DesignTimeDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext(Array.Empty<string>()))
                .Scoped();

            serviceRegistry.For<IPasswordHasher<User>>().Add<AtsPasswordHasher>();
            serviceRegistry.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();
            serviceRegistry.AddTransient<IUserClaimStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();

            serviceRegistry.AddIdentityCore<User>()
                .AddSignInManager()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            serviceRegistry.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            }).AddIdentityCookies(o => { });
        }
```

Edit 2:

Controller Action - result.Succeeded is true

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logon(LogonViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await mUserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

      
                var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Username, model.Password, false, false );

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    mLogger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");

                    try
                    {
                        var sessionState = CreateSessionState(user.Username, mUserStateManager.ClientIpAddress);
                        var sessionData = CreateSessionData(sessionState, user);
                        mSessionWrapper.Session = sessionData;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("SessionCreated",
                        new
                        {
                            returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl)
                                ? Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].ToString()
                                : model.ReturnUrl,
                            username = model.Username,
                            currentpassword = model.ResetToken
                        });

                    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    mLogger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");


                    //return View("Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }


            // Default to returning the original view once more
            return View("Logon", model);
        }
```

User Store and Claims Store - FindByNameAsync and GetClaimsAsync work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Core.Auth.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Core.Auth.Identity.EFCore
{
    public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserClaimStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>
    {
        private bool mDisposed;

        private CustomUserStore() { }

        public CustomUserStore(CustomDbContext context)
        {
            Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        public virtual CustomDbContext Context { get; private set; }

        private DbSet<User> Users => Context.Set<User>();

        #region IUserStore<User> implementation

        public void Dispose()
        {
            mDisposed = true;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            var foundUser = await FindUserById(user, cancellationToken);

            return foundUser?.UserId.ToString();
        }



        public async Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            var foundUser = await FindUserById(user, cancellationToken);

            return foundUser?.Username;
        }

        public Task SetUserNameAsync(User user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(User user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            return await Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId.ToString() == userId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            return Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == normalizedUserName, cancellationToken); 
        }

        #endregion

        #region IUserClaimStore<User> implementation

        public async Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            // Data model is a little "odd" so having to this in a mechanical fashion for now
            var securityRoleIdsForUser = await Context
                .UserToSecurityRoles
                .Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId)
                .Select(x => x.SecurityRoleId)
                .ToArrayAsync( cancellationToken);

            var securityRoles = await Context
                .SecurityRoles
                .Where(x => securityRoleIdsForUser.Contains(x.SecurityRoleId))
                .Select(x => x.SecurityRoleName)
                .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

            var claims = securityRoles.Select(securityRole => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, securityRole)).ToList();

            return claims;
        }

        public Task AddClaimsAsync(User user, IEnumerable<Claim> claims, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task ReplaceClaimAsync(User user, Claim claim, Claim newClaim, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task RemoveClaimsAsync(User user, IEnumerable<Claim> claims, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IList<User>> GetUsersForClaimAsync(Claim claim, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IUserPasswordStore<User> implementation

        public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            var foundUser = await FindUserById(user, cancellationToken);

            return foundUser.Rfc2898PasswordHash;
        }

        public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// Throws if this class has been disposed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void ThrowIfDisposed()
        {
            if (mDisposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
            }
        }

        private async Task<User> FindUserById(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var foundUser = await Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == user.UserId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return foundUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post a fully reproducible example... or at least enough code to debug the issue.  Please post all relevant code.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I have added the container configuration code to the orginal question. This is my first attempt at a non-standard approach and suspect I may  have got things in the wrong order or have unecessary code in there!

Comment: All this code is pretty much irrelevant.  We need the code that is actually failing. Your stores and logic etc.  How can we help you if we cant reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've added more code to my question. As I mentioned in the original question, nothing is actually failing, as in an exception being thrown, what I am seeing is the Controller.User does not end up with any Claims.

Comment: if you place a break point inside the GetClaimsAsync specifically in the return claims... does it return claims?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, spun up the application first thing this morning to double check that claims were being returned which they were (and were yesterday) and much to my amazement I can now see Claims on Controller.User. No code changes made. Cookie issue yesterday perhaps?!

Comment: sounds good.  so maybe you no longer have an issue